# Facebook can't get video likes count

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get number of likes on videos. So I go like 
https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/{video_id}/likes?access_token={token}.

However I always get back empty data even if video has at least some likes.

I've created a token with following permissions: scope="public_profile,email,user_videos,manage_pages,user_likes".

The last thing to mention is that the video is posted by user page. I've also tested the same thing on Graph API Explorer and it doesn't even work there.

I for example can get comments on the same video...

Comment: "user page" - do you mean "user profile" or "page"?

Comment: I mean that this video is posted by user, on a page created by user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The individual likes are likely not available to your app due to privacy concerns (the liking user would probably have to grant your app access to access *their* made likes first)

But since you are only interested in the overall number, asking for the summary should do it:

```
/{video_id}/likes?summary=1
```

or when using field expansion syntax,

```
/{video_id}?fields=likes.summary(1)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!